# Eigen how to find all coplanar faces from triangle mesh normals without looping

Tags: c++, eigen, normals

I have a mesh *which is mostly planar* I'd like to find all the coplanar faces by using normals. I'll take that by finding all normals pointing in the same direction; that is, checking all collinear normal vectors within a tolerance, by a dot product.
But that means I've to check by looping for every vector.

```
MatrixXd VL = ... // Collinear vectors list taken from mesh normals
collinearEpsilon = 1e-8;

for (long i = 0, j = 0; i < VL.rows(); i++)
{
    // get previous vector
    Vector3d p = VL.row(i);

    // loop around last vector
    j = i + 1;
    if (j == size)
    {
        j = 0;
    }

    // get next vector
    Vector3d n = VL.row(j);

    // if dot product is one, they're colinear
    VectorXd CL(1);
    p = p.normalized();
    n = n.normalized();
    CL(0) = 1 - abs(p.dot(n));

    // check with epsilon
    if (CL.isZero(collinearEpsilon))
        // vector is collinear
    else
        // exit on first non-collinear
}
```

Thus my question: is there a better way to check the collinearity of a set of vectors, all together in a more compact way without looping, in Eigen?

EDIT: added assuming mesh is mostly planar

Comment: How large is your input matrix? Can you modify it (e.g. normalize it in-place)? What happens inside `// vector is collinear`?

Comment: Size 20-50k. it can be normalized in place, yes. Initially I put a boolean vector inside "vector is collinear", so to have an array of bools of 0-1 results for colinearity. I omitted it because what I want to know is basically related to how do the dot product check (or any other type of check, if it works) in a mass-like fashion, sparing the loop